# How can I solve this error from flask-admin extension when creating a ModelView?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I am going through the flask-admin tutorial.

As the tutorial explains, when I create an instance of ModelView for my User model by using

```
admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))
```

I get an error which is:
**AttributeError: 'ColumnProperty' object has no attribute 'expression'**

and when I create an instance of ModelView for my Account model by using:

```
admin.add_view(ModelView(Account, db.session))
```

I get an error:
**Exception: Model Account does not have primary key.**

My User model code is:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80))
    email = db.Column(db.String(160))
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    account_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('account.id'))
    account = db.relationship('Account', backref=db.backref('user', lazy='dynamic'))
```

Account model code is:

```
class Account(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
```

**stack trace when creating User ModelView:** http://pastebin.com/gf200CHp

**stack trace when creating Account ModelView:** http://pastebin.com/NYhGBW1Z

I am using flask-sqlalchemy for creating models.
Can someone please suggest how to solve these errors?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the full stack traces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same `Model ... does not have primary key` exception, but it went away after I upgraded SQLAlchemy from 0.7.10 to 0.8.2:

```
sudo pip install SQLAlchemy==0.8.2
```

-Cheers!